# Auth0 LoginResult not able to load Newtonsoft.Json 10.0.0.0

Tags: c#, auth0

I am facing a weird kind of situation while trying to achieve `LoginAsync` using `Auth0.OidcclientWpf` SDK. I am using below code:

```
private async void PerformAuthenticationAsync()
{
    Auth0Client auth0Client = new Auth0Client(new Auth0ClientOptions()
    {
         Domain = "mydomain",
         ClientId = "clientid"
    });

     var extraParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
     extraParameters.Add("connection", "connectionParam");
     var result = await auth0Client.LoginAsync(extraParameters: extraParameters);
}
```

After performing the authentication process, I am getting error:

```
Not able to load NewtonSoftJson.dll version - 10.0.0.0
```

and the source was `Identitymodel.oidclient`. Here after setting `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII` to `True` I can see in the trace that the token for which I am looking for is recieved but `LoginResult` is failed to decode the header.

I tried refering `NewtonSoft.Json dll` version **10.0.2** in my project. Now I am getting exception like:

```
Not able to load NewtonSoftJson.dll version 11.0.0.0
```

and this time the Browser was not even launched to enter credentials.

I am confused which version of `NewtonSoft.Json` dll I should refer? I updated my `IdentityModel.oidcclient` to the latest version. Even after that `IdentityModel.Oidcclient.LoginResult` is complaining for `NewtonSoft.Json version 10.0.0.0` unavailability.

I am not sure what is the real issue. Whether I have to refer both the versions (10 & 11) and how to do that? I would appreciate if someone can help.

**UPDATE**

below is the trace I am getting -

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions' threw an exception.
>   ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions..cctor()    --- End of
>   inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JsonExtensions.DeserializeJwtHeader(String
>   jsonString)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken.Decode(String[]
>   tokenParts, String rawData)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken.Decode(String[]
>   tokenParts, String rawData)    at
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(String
>   token)    at
>   IdentityModel.OidcClient.IdentityTokenValidator.d__4.MoveNext()
>   >

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here, with Auth0.OidcClient 2.2.0.0 and Newtonsoft.Json version 11.0.0.0.

I have no real solution for the problem, either. In the end I implemented a custom assembly resolve handler as a workaround.

To make sure that this does not affect the rest of the application, I am installing the handler only temporarily while the login window is open. I also make sure to only load the assembly named "Newtonsoft.Json". The handler looks for the Newtonsoft.Json assembly in the folder of the executing assembly.